# What are the best ways to show live data in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, wcf-ria-services

I'm using a stream engine that updates my database every second with significant set of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking into using a WCF Duplex Service. I found several articles about implementing it searching for "Silverlight WCF Duplex Service." You should also consider bring back chunks of your data instead of the whole set each time if the data set is significantly large as you mentioned.

Comment: Duplex is not the way I looking for. I've tried to implement duplex in my case this give me app crash

Comment: Another approach is to use DispatchTimer to asynchronously poll the database every few seconds. To optimize: on the server in your service method, you could write code to figure out what has changed and return only that subset of data.

Comment: I think Duplex connection type wraps this approach. I mean that performance will be the same.